# Issue in Passing URL in python tornado framework

Tags: python, tornado

I am passing resource path as below.

```
application = tornado.web.Application(handlers=[ (r"/rsgateway/data/json/eventstore/subscriber/orderid/555555&xyz=1", getUsageHistory),)
```

In the resource path , i need to pass URL. But due to special character like +,$ my script is not returning output . Need to know how to pass url in resource path.

Comment: Where do you have +, $ etc?

Comment: You can use '\' to escape special character. example to find $ use ```r'\$'```

Comment: Thanks, found a  workaround       app = tornado.web.Application([
    url(r"/rsgateway/.*", getUsageHistory), will let me pass url .

Answer (score 0):

You should receive request parameters in handlers. Your code might look something like this:

App:

```
application = tornado.web.Application(handlers=[
(r"/rsgateway/data/json/eventstore/subscriber/orderid/([0-9]+)", UsageHistory),
])
```

and Handler:

```
class UsageHistory(RequestHandler):
    async def get(self, order_id: str):
        xyz = self.request.query_arguments.get('xyz')
        data = await self.orders.get_history(int(order_id), xyz)
        await self.finish(escape.json_encode(data))
```